# Dockerize .net 6 application that uses .NET Framework libraries dll

Tags: .net, docker, .net-6.0

I have a net6.0-windows console application that uses .dll libraries written for .NET Framework 4.8.

I'm trying to dockerize my app, so I autogenerate with visual studio this docker file:

```
 #See https://aka.ms/customizecontainer to learn how to customize your debug container and how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

#Depending on the operating system of the host machines(s) that will build or run the containers, the image specified in the FROM statement may need to be changed.
#For more information, please see https://aka.ms/containercompat

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["Enel3D/LGSExtractor/LGSExtractor.csproj", "Enel3D/LGSExtractor/"]
COPY ["Enel3D/Digitarca.Enel3D/Digitarca.Enel3D.csproj", "Enel3D/Digitarca.Enel3D/"]
COPY ["Libraries/Digitarca.IO.E57/Digitarca.IO.E57.csproj", "Libraries/Digitarca.IO.E57/"]
RUN dotnet restore "Enel3D/LGSExtractor/LGSExtractor.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/Enel3D/LGSExtractor"
RUN dotnet build "LGSExtractor.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "LGSExtractor.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LGSExtractor.dll"]
```

when I build the image it seems ok, but when I run the app in the container I have the exception that it seems the library is not present:

```
Error: Dll was not found.  Process Failed Unhandled exception:
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
by the target of an invocation.  ---> System.DllNotFoundException: Dll
was not found.
```

Instead if I publish my my app locally and run it in publish folder without docker it looks good.

Can you help me?
Thanks!

Comment: There is high chance you will need Windows-based images here.

Comment: so I have to substitute this images FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/runtime:6.0 AS base
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build with other images? Can you indicate what images I have to select?

Comment: Yes, I would try starting from there. Though it is not guaranteed to work.

Comment: Have you truncated some of the error message? Doesn't it say what DLL wasn't found? Did you ensure those DLLs got copied into the container?

Comment: Yes I am. Dll Is present in container. There Is the same situation that I have in local, same libraries